# Skype Web SDK - Only one server, "https://webdir1e.online.lync.com/" is correctly responding to oAuth flows?

Tags: skypedeveloper

I have no problems getting into Skype's Web SDK oAuth flow authentication regarding Skype SignIn when my home pool server is "https://webdir1e.online.lync.com/".

All others - https://webdir2e.online.lync.com/, https://webdir0e.online.lync.com/, https://webdir0e.online.lync.com/, etc... - are returning 403 with "reason="Service does not allow a cross domain request from this origin."

The interactive web sdk page suffers from the same problem:
https://ucwa.skype.com/websdk

After choosing "Azure AD" authentication and filling my "Cliend ID" and including "https://ucwa.skype.com/websdk" in my App's Reply Url's, the demo only loads correctly if the home pool server is "https://webdir1e.online.lync.com/". For others, it keeps waiting forever.

Correct: (notice the home pool server: https://**webdir1e**.online.lync.com/)

[image: Correct oAuth flow]

Incorrect: (notice the home pool server: https://**webdir0e**.online.lync.com/)

[image: Incorrect oAuth flow]

This was working last week, any clue to what is happening?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Having the same issue. We've opened a ticket to MS about this and they have people looking at this, let's hope it gets resolved soon. The issue popped up on Monday and is obviously a misconfiguration issue on their side.

Comment: @slavikko Thanks for the feedback. Exactly the same with us, from Monday on it stopped working. The api is basically dead right now, so we hope the problem can be fixed as soon as possible...

Comment: Exactly the same issue for me. I cannot tell exactly when it started but several days ago since now, may be at the end of previous week. A single server https://webdir1e.online.lync.com is OK, others webdirgb1, webdir0e, webdir2e all response with 403 and header X-Ms-diagnostics:28070;source="AM30E00EDG14.infra.lync.com";reason="Service does not allow a cross domain request from this origin.". The response body tells "403 - Forbidden: Access is denied. You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied."

Comment: @PeterNedonosko If you substitute the "origins" parameter "https://webdir.online.lync.com/autodiscover/autodiscoverservice.svc/root" by the actual one that works "https://webdir1e.online.lync.com/Autodiscover/AutodiscoverService.svc/root", the service picks up and works. Documentation clearly states to not mess with the "origins" parameter, but right now is the only option.

Comment: @NunoMiguelFonseca thank you. It's indeed a way to go until they'll fix the things. Thank you.

Comment: Heard back from MS about an hour ago, a fix is rolling out on the servers now, so the issue should be fixed soon(ish).

Comment: @slavikko Thanks for the feedback! Let's hope it does :)

Comment: It does. With the only autodiscovery origin: https://webdir.online.lync.com/autodiscover/autodiscoverservice.svc/root it uses different servers (webdir2e, webdirgb1 etc) and all them work well.